# Git 'unable to unlink old file (permission denied)' error, but updating permissions doesn't work

Tags: git

I was working on a single file in a branch (Branch-A), committed my code and pushed up my changes. I then checked out a new branch (Branch-B) did some work but noticed I was getting changes on the same file I worked on in Branch-A.

I ran `git checkout -- /file.php` to revert the changes, but got the message:

> error: unable to unlink old 'file.php' (Permission denied)

Googling the issue, I find a lot of StackOverflow answers saying to change the file's permissions, which I tried:

```
chmod ug+w file.php
```

and

```
chmod 777 file.php
```

But still I get the same issue with the same error message.

Would anyone know what this is or what I could do next?

Comment: Try using root permission `sudo chmod 777 file.php` or check if you have appropriate git user for checking out the repository

Comment: On a Linux or Unix system, inspect the permissions of the *containing directory*. You must be able to write the containing directory to remove a file within it.

Comment: Yes, you are right @torek. Would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: @amrs-tech: If that were the problem, you would have gotten an error message on the original non-root `chmod`. Also, `777` is excessive; there's no point in giving all users read, write, and execute permission. `644` or `755` is enough (the latter only if it needs to be executable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Unix or Linux based system, the ability to remove a file—or create one, for that matter—is typically controlled by the permissions of the file's containing directory.  Hence `file.php` depends on the permissions of the work-tree (in this case `.`, or the path to it):

```
$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 ...
```

or:

```
# in a different directory
$ ls -ld
drwxrwxr-x 46 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 29 23:34 .
```

for instance.

In the former case, the directory is owned by `root` and is writable only by `root` so only the super-user can create or remove files.  In the second case, the directory is owned by user `vagrant` and group `vagrant`, and is both user- and group-writable, so user `vagrant` may create or delete files, and so may any user who is a member of the `vagrant` group (which on this particular system is only the user `vagrant` anyway).

If you, as a user, do not have write-access to the containing directory, you can change the ownership (user and/or group) and mode as necessary, or do operations as the super-user (who generally can do anything even if the permissions are set to deny access to `root`) via `sudo`.  It's wise to limit the amount of work done as the super-user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, check first the rights associated with that file

```
cd /path/to/repo
# assuming file.php is at the root directory of the repository
ls -alrth file.php
git checkout -- file.php
```

(try the checkout without the `/`)

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453185/6309), make sure the file is not opened by any other tool/editor.
See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12547305/6309), and try setting `git config core.sharedRepository true` inside your repository.